# Derivative of complex-valued function and partial derivatives.

Tags: complex-analysis, examples-counterexamples

Let $f(x+iy)=u(x,y)+i\,v(x,y)$

1. Cauchy-Riemann Equations are satisfied at $z_0$
2. $u, v, u_x, u_y, v_x, v_y$ are defined on some open neighbourhood of $z_0$
3. $u, v, u_x, u_y, v_x, v_y$ are continuous at $z_0$

$\implies f'(z_0)$ exists.

Can you show me a complex-valued function $f$ such that $f'(z_0)$ exists but at least one of $(2)$ or $(3)$ is not satisfied? In other words, is there a counterexample to the converse?

The book went through a great deal of work to show that the converse is true if $f$ is analytic at $z_0$. So there is a possibility things fall apart in general.

Comment: The limit condition for complex derivatives is stronger than in $\mathbb R^{2}$. If $f^{'}(z_0)$ exists then $f$ is analytic at $z_0$.

Comment: That last statement is not entirely true. For example, using the theorem stated, one can show that $f(z)=|z|^2$ is differentiable only at the origin. Thus $f'(0)$ exists yet $f$ is nowhere analytic.

Comment: Yes. My mistake. I was thinking we had $f^{'}$ in some neighborhood of $z_0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ be an arbitrary bounded function. Then for 
$f(z)=z^2g(z)$, by definition, $f'(0)$ exists and is $0$. However, you may choose $g$ as pathological as possible, so that $u$ and $v$ have no continuity at all on $\mathbb{C}\backslash\{0\}$.

Comment: When I calculate it, I get $$f'(0)= \lim_{h \to 0} 0 \cdot \frac{g(h)-g(0)}{h}$$
How did you get $0$? And why $\mathbb{C} \backslash \{0\}$. I wanted a function where $u$ (or $v$ or any of their partial derivatives) is not continuous at the point where the derivative exists.

Comment: @genepeer: I don't know how you get that, but on the right hand side, the expression inside the limit is nothing but $0$ for every $h\ne 0$.

Comment: I used the definition $$f'(z_0) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(z_0+h)-f(z_0)}{h}$$

Comment: @genepeer: You may choose $g$, such that all the partial derivatives $u_x$, $u_y$, $v_x$, $v_y$ does not exist except for $z=0$. This example violates your assumption 2.

Comment: @genepeer: Following your definition, now $z_0=f(z_0)=0$, so $f'(0)=\lim_{h\to 0}hg(h)$. Since $h\to 0$ and $g$ is bounded, the limit exists and is $0$.

Comment: I see. So something as pathological as: $$g(z) = \begin{cases} 1 & z \in \mathbb{Q}^2 \\ 0 & \text{Otherwise} \end{cases}$$
I've never written $\mathbb{Q}^2$ before but I thought it was the easiest way to say rational coordinates :)

Comment: @genepeer: Yes, this is what I exactly mean. Just one more caution: for your construction of $g$, some partial derivatives still exist when $z\notin \mathbb{Q}^2$. For example, $u(\sqrt{2},y)\equiv 0$, so $u_y(\sqrt{2},y)\equiv 0$. However, it does not matter much, because the partial derivatives cannot always exist on an open set. If you have interests, you can construct $g$, such that all the partial derivatives of $u,v$ does not exist on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$, or all of them exist in some neighborhood of $0$, but not continuous at $0$.